# crm workflow steps - asynchronous or synchronous?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow, dynamics-crm

Can anyone confirm, when I have steps in a workflow in MS Dynamics 2011, do they run  asynchronous or synchronous?

TIA
Dan

Comment: Workflows are Async. Read this for details : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309471.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The execution of a 2011 workflow is asynchronous but the steps in the workflow will run synchronously.

For example, a workflow on Create of an Account will execute after a new Account record is created - i.e., the record is created and control returned to the user. But if there are 5 steps in that workflow they will execute synchronously - so the first step will execute before the second and so on.

**UPDATED FOR CRM 2013 AND FORWARD**

With the introduction of Synchronous (real-time) workflows starting in Dynamics CRM 2013 you need to check the workflow to determine if it running synchronously or asynchronously. The steps within the workflow will still be synchronous, regardless of the workflow type.

Answer (score 1):

Steps are ran asynchronously as a part of workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Steps are also asynchronous which I don't like :( and I tried many timed to use wait condition but it never worked